# Доступ запрещен при входе на localhost

Tags: apache, localhost

при входе на  localhost/127.0.0.1:61613 у меня появляется эта ошибка
в чем может быть проблема и как это решить?

```
Доступ запрещён!
У Вас нет прав доступа к этому объекту. Файл недоступен для чтения, или сервер не может его прочитать.

Если Вы считаете, что это ошибка сервера, пожалуйста, сообщите об этом веб-мастеру.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.8
```

Comment: А если зайти по нормальному IP сервера? Возможно просто сервер настроен так чтобы не отвечать на 127.0.0.1

Comment: тогда пишет, что объект не найден

Comment: Без конфигов сервера это гадание, нужны конфиги и онимание есть ли файл в root каталоге сервера? есть ли у сервера права на этот файл?

Comment: А в целом алгоритм такой, проверьте правильно ли прописан путь для www-root директории, есть ли там реально тот файл который вы пытаетесь открыть, и пользователь под которым работает сервер имеет права на доступ к этому файлу. Если всё ОК то возможно файл открыть в другой программе и она блокирует доступ к этому файлу. А лучше посмотрите логи сервера, возможно ответ там ;)

Comment: я установила RabbitMQ и порт 61613 это для плагина STOMP, когда  я запустила приложения для которого я это делала , то мне вылезла ошибка , ну и когда я перехожу на сервер ошибка 403, если честно, я не очень азюираюсь в серверах и во всем этом , так что , если бы вы могли мне объяснить ,что именно я должна сделать и посомтреть

Comment: Откуда же мне знать что у вас за приложение и как оно работает. Заплатите кому-нибудь, или читайте мануалы от вашего приложения, там обычно есть примеры кофигов для разных сред.